# MySQL update/insert strips backslashes for unicode entries

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, backslash

I'm trying to insert/update a SQL field with JSON data that encodes unicode as \u, but it's stripping it out:

```
"Sauteéd -> ["Saute\u00e9d"]
```

However, it's being saved in the database like this:

```
["Sauteu00e9d"]
```

I've tried countless preg_replace and str_replace methods, but none of them work. Is there something I can do about this - it's driving me mad.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I program in PHP

Comment: how do you connect to the database simple, pdo or even with a dbal/orm like doctrine/propel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you use PHP

In that case you should use mysql_real_escape string instead of preg replace.
It's easier and much better against SQL injections.

Comment: Not against SQL injections but against such problems in the first place. mysql_real_escape string is not somewhat "protection". it's just a part of proper query syntax.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php - There's a good explanation why it's good against injections.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is obviously now deprecated so here is how you would do it in modern PHP:

```
$value = $mysql_conn->real_escape_string("Saute\u00e9d");
$query = "update so_and_so set param = '$value' where var1 = 'somevalue'";
...
...
```

or however you happen to run your queries...